# Printing only final result instead of all intermediate results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that reads data from a file. Every fourth line is a year and I need to use a counter to count the total number of years but when I run the program, the output window shows this:

```
The total number of years is 1.
The total number of years is 2.
The total number of years is 3.
The total number of years is 4.
The total number of years is 5.
The total number of years is 6.
The total number of years is 7.
The total number of years is 8.
The total number of years is 9.
The total number of years is 10.
The total number of years is 11.
The total number of years is 12.
The total number of years is 13.
The total number of years is 14.
The total number of years is 15.
```

I only need to print the last line, not all of them. This is how I have written it:

```
count = 0       
line_count = 0
total_year = 0

while line != '':
    count += 1


    if len(line) > 1:


        if line_count % 4 == 0:
            total_year += 1
            year=int(line)
            line = infile.readline()
            line_count+=1

    print('The total number of years is ' + str(total_year)+ '.')
```

How do I get it to display only one line without changing any of the other information?

Comment: Why not just put a print statement outside the while loop...?

Comment: Why not provide the code that acutally `print(....)`s anything? Its always easier to solve your problems in your code when the code in shown here is the same that produced the problem in the first place ...

Comment: Move the `print` outside of the loop and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

### Your problem

The indentation is wrong. Your `print()` is inside the `while` loop:

```
while line != '':
    [...]
    print('The total number of years is ' + str(total_year) + '.')
```

Thus, after each loop, this `print()` is executed.

### Solution

Simply remove an indentation level before your `print()`:

```
while line != '':
    [...]
print('The total number of years is ' + str(total_year) + '.')
```

With your `print()` now located outside the `while` loop, it will only be executed after the `while` loop is done.